# Can I make IntelliJ IDEA show the warning plates directly in the code?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, warnings

When you hover the mouse over a warning tick on the scroll bar on the right, IntelliJ IDEA shows a small preview with the warning placed directly in the code, like this:

[image]

All the code is rendered as usual in this preview, but there's also a warning plate:

> Redundant `Unit` return type.

So, can I make these warning plates always show up in the editor, without mouse-hovering on the scroll bar?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.